# Div Wider than Viewport

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am currently coding a responsive menu using the checkbox hack and noticed that when my menu appears after clicking the hamburger icon, it is wider than the viewport. The menu has a fixed position and a flex display. I have added red borders around elements to give show this issue. Here is the relevant code:

```css
/* General styles */
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  font-family: 'Miriam Libre', sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
a:hover {
  color: #ea3c53;
}
/* Navigation styles */
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #222222;
}
.donate {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 21px;
}
nav .brand {
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
nav label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 21px;
  background: #63E2C6;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}
nav > label > span {
  display: block;
  margin: 4px auto;
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  top: -100vh;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #222;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.85);
}
.menu li {
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .menu {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <!-- Top bar -->
    <a href="link" target="_blank" class="donate">Donate</a>
    <img src="media/logo2.png" alt="Logo" class="brand">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav">
    <label for="nav">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#home">Home.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#mission">Mission.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact.</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

So, my question is, why is this happening? After all, I do have the width set to 100%, not 110%.

Comment: Try adding * {box-sizing: border-box} to your CSS

Comment: remove browser-added padding/margins by putting *{margin:0; padding:0; }  at top of your css. That should help.  Also ensure you include the meta to set the viewport to device-width ``<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have margin on your body element. Add:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

There is also default margin and padding on your `ul` element that is also being set to `width: 100%`;

I recommend checking all of your primary containers, looking at them in your browser's inspector will highlight when you have additional spacing on an element that you may not be accounting for.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful.